# Is there a possibility to hide fields from the Designer in VS Windows Form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using VS 2010.

I want to hide a textbox from [Design] and I still can get Text in this textbox.

If I set properties visible = true, I can't get the Text in this textbox.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Uh, say what?.. What do you mean by "get its value"?

Comment: Umm, visible = false should work, I don't see any problem.

Comment: I still don't get it. What do you want, when you say the "value of this control"?

Comment: Where are you trying to place the TextBox? Don't place it with the others in InitializeComponents(), but do the same sort of thing that's done in that method. Also, which version of .NET are you targeting? 4.0?

Comment: furyfish, what do you mean _I want to hide a textbox from [Design]_?